# Unable to reach web interface on my new switch (Zyxel GS1900 24E)

Tags: networking, switch

The manual states I am to reach the web interface at http://192.168.1.1 but when I try all I get is time outs.

It's brand new, straight out of the box, no tampering. All network drives and internet access works just fine except the web interface to the switch.

I have my router connected to the switch on port 1. Security cameras and NAS are on other ports 4-8 and 12-20.

Anyone with experience with this switch that can help me out?

Comment: Are you sure, the address it has assigned to it, is that address?  The switch would only be assigned 192.168.1.1 if your DHCP server assigned addresses within that subnet

Comment: I would disable wireless (if any connected) and set up the IP manually on the wired connection on your computer and connect the switch and computer directly as the [manual](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/GS1900-24/user_guide/GS1900-24_V1_Ed2.pdf) does not say that the switch acquires itself an IP by means of DHCP. As you did not say what your routers network is, it might even clash. In the past most routers had the 192.168.0.1 (or 254) /24 IP, nowadays I see more 192.168.1.1 IPs or even (my latest router) has a 192.168.8.1/24 IP and it allows me to change only the last two octets.

Comment: @Ramhound I looked and the DHCP start is set to 192.168.1.64. However I tried that IP as well...hmmm

Comment: So does this switch show up in the list of clients connected to your DHCP server?

Comment: I ended up returning the switch, because the store said it might not work properly